# How to make a button open another app with Java/Android?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to learn to make a simple app that has a few buttons with each opening another app to eliminate the need for another apps. I just can't figure it out. Also, can I place more than one button in this activity to open another app? I can't really find that answer either.

```
Button batteryhistory = (Button)findViewById(R.string.BatteryHistoryButtonDialog);

    batteryhistory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
      Intent i = new Intent(); 
       ComponentName n = new 
       ComponentName("com.android.settings", 
       "com.android.settings.BatteryHistory"); 
       i.setComponent(n); 
       startActivity(i);
```

Thanks so much for the help :D

Comment: what happens when you run your code? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hope this implementation will work :

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.ImageButton01) {

            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                // Toast.makeText(this, "Application Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setClassName("com.xxx.your_package_name",
                        "com.xxx.your_class_name");

                startActivity(i);

            }
        }
```

The only thing is that you will have to install the application before hand.

Comment: Thanks. I will try when I get home. And rate you helped.

Comment: Axarydax, when I run the app, I get a fc. It opens fine. But when I click the button it FCs. I am going to try Sen's code now.

Comment: I finally got it to work. I wouldn't have been able without ya, Sen. I combined yours and mine and got it! Thanks a bunch, Sen!

Answer (score 1):

here is the code to open an app(ex whatsapp) from another app

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button bClock = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        bClock.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                PackageManager managerclock = getPackageManager();
                i = managerclock.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.whatsapp");
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```