# Integrate two android apps into one

Tags: android, apk

I have two android applications. I want to integrate them into one but I don't have source code for these two apps. I just have apk files. So is there any way to do it? 
For the details, I want to create an app which contains two button, the first button will fire the first app and the second button will fire the second app. So I just need to embed these two apps in my main app. Can it be done without source codes?

Comment: Possible duplicated : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2923265/1050058), [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4644666/1050058), [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3872063/1050058)

Answer (score 1):

Q: I have two android applications. I don't have source code for these two apps. I just have apk files.  Can I integrate them into one app?

A: No.

But you *can* write an app that will *launch* either app.

For example:

- [How do I programmatically launch a specific application in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343432/how-do-i-programmatically-launch-a-specific-application-in-android)
- [Open another one application from our application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342655/open-another-one-application-from-our-application)

  `Intent intent = new Intent("com.twidroid.SendTweet");`

Comment: In that case, users need to install three apps in order to call these two apps from my main app. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity.this,nextActivity.class);

this.finish();

startActivity(intent);
```